# Salesforce Trusted CA - Trial certificate

Tags: single-sign-on, saml

Here is list of certificates trusted by Salesforce.
http://wiki.apexdevnet.com/page/Outbound_Messaging_SSL_CA_Certificates

Is there any certificate which is available on trial basis & trusted by Salesforce?

(After much of search I couldn't find any. If you think there is none, please submit that too as an answer)

Answer (score 1):

After much of research, I have reached conclusion that

There is no trial certificate that Salesforce Supports.